# Android GridView - how to setColumnWidth in dp

Tags: android, gridview

I have a GridView which, depending on the situation, may have 3 or 4
columns.  The column widths need to change depending on whether 3 or 4
are being displayed.  I therefore can't hardcode the width into the
layout XML containing the GridView, it must be set via the
setColumnWidth command.

The problem is that setColumnWidth can only set the width in pixels,
and I want to specify the width in dp.  How can I do this, or must I
create 2 layouts with the column width hardcoded into each in dp?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code in order to convert dp to px:

```
Resources r = getResources();
float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 14, r.getDisplayMetrics());
```

But since you change the number of columns from 3 to 4 and vice versa, the column width does not adjust itself?

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  Also the column width does adjust itself but I prefer to have absolute control over how things look...